# OAuth2, Spring Авторизация через vk - ошибка invalid_token_response tokenType cannot be null

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, spring-security, oauth2, token

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию на сайте через социальные сети такие как VK, OK, Google, Facebook в Spring Security.

C google авторизация работает, а вот через VK нет.
Авторизация проходит успешно, но на этапе получения токена вылетает ошибка, причем в отладчике я её не вижу.

Ниже лог запросов:

1. запрос на получения кода авторизации

> https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=123456&settings=43434&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.ru%2Fapi%2Foauth2%2Fcallback%2Fvk&response_type=code&group_ids=&token_type=0&v=5.95&state=CmVzKVelhcCWp6Uq6ftQ=%3D&display=page&ip_h=085263ad5a70&hash=1560095643_b996766c01&https=1

2. Тут я получил код авторизации

> https://xxxx.ru/api/oauth2/callback/vk?code=
>   rMt4GzXza4FuqnorlnNO&state=CmVzKVelhcCWp6Uq6ftQ=

3. далее приходит ошибка

> https://xxxx.ru/redirect?error=[invalid_token_response] An error
>   occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token
>   Response: Error while extracting response for type [class
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse]
>   and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: An
>   error occurred reading the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: tokenType
>   cannot be null; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tokenType cannot be null

Почему tokenType не может быть null не могу понять.

Настройку oauth client я делаю в коде по скольку все конфиги лежал в базе.

Выбор клиента авторизации

```
public class CustomClientRegistration {
  @Autowired
  private SocialNetworkDataRepository socialNetworkDataRepository;

  public ClientRegistration getRegistration(String registrationId) {

    SocialNetworkDataModel model = socialNetworkDataRepository.findByProvider(AuthProviderEnum.valueOf(registrationId));

    if (model == null) {
      return null;
    }

    AuthProviderEnum client = AuthProviderEnum.valueOf(registrationId);

    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = null;

    if (client == AuthProviderEnum.google) {
      clientRegistration = CustomOAuth2Provider.getGoogle(model);
    }

    if (client == AuthProviderEnum.facebook) {
      clientRegistration = CustomOAuth2Provider.getFacebook(model);
    }

    if (client == AuthProviderEnum.vk) {
      clientRegistration = CustomOAuth2Provider.getVk(model);
    }

    return clientRegistration;
  }
}
```

Настройка провайдера

```
public class CustomOAuth2Provider {
  public static ClientRegistration getGoogle(SocialNetworkDataModel model) {
    return CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder(model.getProvider().name())
            .scope(model.getScope().split(","))
            .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}")
            .clientId(model.getAppId()).clientSecret(model.getSecret()).build();
  }

  public static ClientRegistration getVk(SocialNetworkDataModel model) {
    ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder(model.getProvider().name(), ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST, "{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}");
    builder.scope(model.getScope().split(","));
    builder.authorizationUri("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?v=5.95");
    builder.tokenUri("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token");
    builder.userInfoUri("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get");
    builder.clientName("vkontakte");
    builder.redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}");
    builder.clientId(model.getAppId());
    builder.clientSecret(model.getSecret());
    builder.registrationId("vk");
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

Конфигурация Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private static List<String> clients = Arrays.asList("google", "vk", "facebook");

  @Bean
  protected ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
    List<ClientRegistration> registrations = clients.stream()
        .map(c -> customClientRegistration().getRegistration(c))
        .filter(registration -> registration != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {

    return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(
        clientRegistrationRepository());
  }         

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthExceptionEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
        .authorizationEndpoint()
        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
        .and()
        .redirectionEndpoint()
        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
        .and()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
        .and()
        .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

    // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  ////*************....
}
```

Comment: У вас удалось решить  проблему? Я сегодня всю ночь просидел и вчерне задачу решил, хотя у меня и очень некрасиво получилось, т.к. пришлось совсем глубоко закопаться в недра спринга чтобы вручную прикреплять токены к запросам и прокидывать email юзера через цепочку запросов. И всё потому, что у ВК сделано странно: мыло возвращается вместе с `access_token`, запрос на который требует `client_id` и `client_secret` в качестве параметров, вместо `Basic` авторизации, а запрос юзера имеет нестандартный формат и также не принимает токен в заголовке.

Comment: Мне пришлось подсунуть свой accessTokenResponseClient в WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: Ага, я примерно так же сделал и как-то оно заработало, хотя нервов съело очень много)

Comment: помогла статься https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests.
Реализовал свой CustomTokenResponseConverter от  implements Converter<Map<String, String>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> где руками проставляю 
OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType accessTokenType = OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER; Как оказалось vk не возвращает тип токена и спрингу сносит крышу.

Comment: Ага, я точно также и сделал и потом эту же статью нашёл) Правда, пришлось ещё с настройками клиента помучиться - ВК хочет `form` для `clientAuthenticationMethod` и `userInfoAuthenticationMethod`.

Comment: да, да)) тоже самое делал и ClientAuthenticationMethod перенастроил, у спринга только, google, facebook github реализован, опять же мне помогла статься https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

Comment: Может вы тогда и ответ опубликуете с рабочим кодом? Наверняка кому-то ещё это может пригодится)

Comment: Я собирался, но вылетело из головы, завтра обязательно выложу код, спасибо что напомнили ))

Comment: С меня однозначно плюс будет)

Comment: Относительно похожий тикет: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/676

Answer (score 5):

Потратив почти весь день закопавшись в глубь sprign разбираясь что же не так, я нашел в чем была проблема, надеюсь эта информация кому то  сэкономит кучу времени и нервных клеток.

Оказывается Vk в ответе получения токена не возвращается тип токена token_type Bearer, от сюда и срабатывает исключение "tokenType cannot be null".
Но это часть проблемы, также Vk в месте с токеном возвращает email пользователя, плюс на запрос информации о пользователе по токену, ответ зачем то заворачивается в дополнительное  поле "response" из за этого в OAuth2UserService при попытке получить  Map срабатывает исключение. Запрос и разбор ответа пришлось делать вручную.

Для решения этой проблемы мне очень помогли статьи мною глубоко уважаемого Вaeldung.

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

а также серия статей - авторизация пользователей через социальные сети
 - https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

1.Oбработчик ответа получения токена.

```
public class CustomTokenResponseConverter implements Converter<Map<String, String>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> {

  @Override
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponse convert(Map<String, String> tokenResponseParameters) {
    String accessToken = tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    long expiresIn = Long.valueOf(tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN));


    OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType accessTokenType = OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER;

    Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = new HashMap<>();

    tokenResponseParameters.forEach((s, s2) -> {
      additionalParameters.put(s, s2);
    });

    return OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.withToken(accessToken)
            .tokenType(accessTokenType)
            .expiresIn(expiresIn)
            .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
            .build();
  }
}
```

тут и происходит вся магия, вот эта строчка - OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType accessTokenType = OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER;

2.Настраиваем клиента получения информации о пользователе по токену.
ClientRegistration

```
  public static ClientRegistration getVk() {
    ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder("vk", ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST, "{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}");
    builder.scope("xxxxx");
    builder.authorizationUri("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?v=5.95");
    builder.tokenUri("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token");
    builder.userInfoUri("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?{user_id}&v=5.95&fields=photo_id,verified,sex,bdate,city,country,photo_max,home_town,has_photo&display=popup&lang=ru&access_token=xxxxx");
    builder.clientName("vkontakte");
    builder.redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}");
    builder.clientId("xxxxx");
    builder.clientSecret("xxxx");
    builder.userNameAttributeName("user_id");
    builder.registrationId("vk");
    return builder.build();
  }
```

3.Настраиваем CustomOAuth2UserService от DefaultOAuth2UserService где запрашивается информация о пользователе.

```
@Service
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

  @Override
  public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {

    OAuth2User oAuth2User;
    if (oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId().equals("vk")) {
      oAuth2User = loadVkUser(oAuth2UserRequest);
    } else {
      oAuth2User = super.loadUser(oAuth2UserRequest);
    }

    try {
      return processOAuth2User(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2User);
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
      throw new AuthException(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // Throwing an instance of AuthenticationException will trigger the OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler
      throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    }
  }

  private OAuth2User processOAuth2User(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
    OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo = OAuth2UserInfoFactory.getOAuth2UserInfo(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), oAuth2User.getAttributes());

    .....
    return CustomUserPrincipal.create(socialUser, oAuth2User.getAttributes());
  }


  private OAuth2User loadVkUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) {
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("Authorization", oAuth2UserRequest.getAccessToken().getTokenType().getValue() + " " + oAuth2UserRequest.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
    HttpEntity<?> httpRequest = new HttpEntity(headers);
    String uri = oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri();
    String userNameAttributeName = oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName();
    uri = uri.replace("{user_id}", userNameAttributeName + "=" + oAuth2UserRequest.getAdditionalParameters().get(userNameAttributeName));

    try {
      ResponseEntity<Object> entity = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, httpRequest, Object.class);
      Map<String, Object> response = (Map) entity.getBody();
      ArrayList valueList = (ArrayList) response.get("response");
      Map<String, Object> userAttributes = (Map<String, Object>) valueList.get(0);
      userAttributes.put(userNameAttributeName, oAuth2UserRequest.getAdditionalParameters().get(userNameAttributeName));      
      ......

      Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singleton(new OAuth2UserAuthority(userAttributes));
      return new DefaultOAuth2User(authorities, userAttributes, userNameAttributeName);

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      throw new BaseRuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
  }
}
```

4.Все классы инициализируем в WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static List<String> clients = Arrays.asList("google", "vk", "facebook", "ok", "yandex");

  @Autowired
  private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

  @Autowired
  private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

  @Autowired
  private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

  ....


  @Bean
  protected CustomClientRegistration customClientRegistration() {
    return new CustomClientRegistration();
  }

  @Bean
  protected ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
    List<ClientRegistration> registrations = clients.stream()
        .map(c -> customClientRegistration().getRegistration(c))
        .filter(registration -> registration != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
  }  

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthExceptionEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
        .authorizationEndpoint().authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository(), "/oauth2/authorize"))
        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
        .and()
        .redirectionEndpoint()
        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
        .and()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
        .and()
        .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

    // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.oauth2Login().tokenEndpoint().accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient());
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient(){
    DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
            new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(new CustomRequestEntityConverter());

    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter =
            new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
    tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setTokenResponseConverter(new CustomTokenResponseConverter());

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(
            new FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter));
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

    accessTokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);
    return accessTokenResponseClient;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, единственное, что можно предложить - вместо регистрации ClientRegistration и Provider через код явно, можно просто указать соответствующие проперти в yml или properties и автоконфигурация спринг сама добавит новый провайдер и клиента.

Comment: Речь идёт о проперти `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.vk.props` и `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.vk.props`

Comment: Согласен, но одно из требований было, чтобы clientId, clientSecret и т.д., тащить из БД при запуске сервиса